# JBoss salted DatabaseServerLoginModule on AS 7.1

Tags: java, authentication, hash, jboss7.x, salt

I'm trying to set up a secure login for my application.
To achieve this I wanted to salt my hash and maybe use an iteration count.
The [official forums](https://community.jboss.org/thread/199318) don't seem to answer that so I was wondering how to get this to work if I want to stick to my security strategy.  Alternatively I could just leave salting, but I don't think this would be a good idea.
So my question is:
Are there any workarounds to achieve such secure storage here or what is the best practice to handle logins on JBoss AS nowadays?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Almost a year passed and when reviewing this code section I finally found a (maybe not decent, but working) solution:
**Don't let the `DatabaseLoginModule` hash your passwords, hash and salt them yourself.**
In my application I use the login mechanisms provided by Servlet 3.0:
`HttpServletRequest.login(userLogin, pass);`
The crucial point I missed is that you can hash and salt the plain password manually just before the `login()`-call. The `LoginModule` will then match the hashes with those saved in the database.
Maybe that's not the solution I originally wanted, but it doesn't add any unnecessary complexity.